# How to grab data off a website

Tags: c#, html, url, web-crawler

I am building a database of images and would like to automate the process. I am somewhat familiar with HTML, and my core program is built in C#. What would be a good library to use that could help me download a page as HTML, and grab the URL links on the page to the desired image? I am familiar with how to download images from URL already, so that does not need to be addressed.

(Library or other language. The database building and the program do not need to be combined.)

Comment: Please research before asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to build a **crawler** or **website spider** which will grab the stuff from websites. There is a parsing library called **HtmlAgilityPack** which will help you to do that very easily. [This post will tell you how to use this library.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)

Hope it helps!